# Using indirect with a range of separate cells

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to be able to write down in a cell a comma-separated list of cells, and use that with `INDIRECT()` to put it in other functions like `SUM()` and `MAX()` and the likes. I don't actually care if the list is separated by commas or any other character.

So far, putting a simple comma-separated list into `INDIRECT` like so:

```
=INDIRECT("A1,A4")
```

Will produce an error:

```
Function `INDIRECT` parameter 1 value is 'A1,A4'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.
```

I've tried replacing the `,` by a `;` and a `+` to no avail.

Mind you, the above example is simplified. "A1,A4" should eventually be loaded from another cell's contents (on the same sheet).

I'm not 100% sure that using `INDIRECT()` is the most correct approach, but I can't think of anything else. Whatever the solution might be, I do have a couple of limitations:

- The referenced cells are not next to each other, which will exempt the use of array notation like `A1:A4`.
- I don't want to use custom functions, as they slow down the loading and updating a sheet prohibitively, and don't work well (if at all) in the mobile app.
- The list of cells must be easily updatable by changing them just in a cell. This likely prevents the use of Named Range (which, as far as I can tell, also don't support what I want anyway).

What would you recommend to be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

you may wanna try something like this:

[image: 0]

Comment: Okay, this is perhaps heading in the right direction. But the other half of the problem is the most important one. How would you propose to have cell coordinates listed in a cell and passing that list on to something like SUM()?

Comment: just put sum in front like: =SUM({A1,A3,B10})

Comment: If I do that, I would have to keep the same list in each cell where I want to calculate a SUM, AVG, MAX, whatever, This is why I need to keep the list of cells as text in a separate cell.